How to add a native_module when creating an electron-forge package
An error occurs when packaging an app that uses serialport as an electron-forge.
(It works in the test (npm run start).)
enter image description here
Added externals to the webpack.main.config.ts and webpack.render.config.ts files.
//webpack.main.config.ts
import type { Configuration } from 'webpack';

import { rules } from './webpack.rules';
import { plugins } from './webpack.plugins';

export const mainConfig: Configuration = {
  /**
   * This is the main entry point for your application, it's the first file
   * that runs in the main process.
   */
  entry: './src/app/index.ts',
  // Put your normal webpack config below here
  module: {
    rules
  },
  plugins,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.css', '.json'],
  },
  externals: {
    serialport: "serialport",
    "@serialport": "@serialport"
  }
};


//webpack.render.config.ts
import type { Configuration } from 'webpack';

import { rules } from './webpack.rules';
import { plugins } from './webpack.plugins';

rules.push({
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }],
});

export const rendererConfig: Configuration = {
  module: {
    rules,
  },
  plugins,
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.jsx', '.tsx', '.css'],
  },
  externals: {
    serialport: "serialport",
    "@serialport": "@serialport"
  }
};

also added hooks to forge.config.ts.
hooks: {
import type { ForgeConfig } from '@electron-forge/shared-types';
import { MakerSquirrel } from '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel';
import { MakerZIP } from '@electron-forge/maker-zip';
import { MakerDeb } from '@electron-forge/maker-deb';
import { MakerRpm } from '@electron-forge/maker-rpm';
import { AutoUnpackNativesPlugin } from '@electron-forge/plugin-auto-unpack-natives';
import { WebpackPlugin } from '@electron-forge/plugin-webpack';
import { FusesPlugin } from '@electron-forge/plugin-fuses';
import { FuseV1Options, FuseVersion } from '@electron/fuses';
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import { spawnSync } from "child_process";
import { globSync } from "glob";

import { mainConfig } from './webpack.main.config';
import { rendererConfig } from './webpack.renderer.config';

const config: ForgeConfig = {
  packagerConfig: {
    asar: true,
  },
  rebuildConfig: {

  },
  makers: [new MakerSquirrel({}), new MakerZIP({}, ['darwin']), new MakerRpm({}), new MakerDeb({})],
  plugins: [
    new AutoUnpackNativesPlugin({}),
    new WebpackPlugin({
      mainConfig,
      renderer: {
        config: rendererConfig,
        entryPoints: [
          {
            html: './src/index.html',
            js: './src/renderer.tsx',
            name: 'main_window',
            preload: {
              js: './src/app/preload.ts',
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    }),
    // Fuses are used to enable/disable various Electron functionality
    // at package time, before code signing the application
    new FusesPlugin({
      version: FuseVersion.V1,
      [FuseV1Options.RunAsNode]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableCookieEncryption]: true,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableNodeOptionsEnvironmentVariable]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableNodeCliInspectArguments]: false,
      [FuseV1Options.EnableEmbeddedAsarIntegrityValidation]: true,
      [FuseV1Options.OnlyLoadAppFromAsar]: true,
    }),
  ],
  hooks: {
    packageAfterPrune: async (_forgeConfig, buildPath, _electronVersion, platform, _arch) => {
      /**
       * Serialport, usb and uiohook-napi are problematic libraries to run in Electron.
       * When Electron app is been built, these libraries are not included properly in the final executable.
       * What we do here is to install them explicitly and then remove the files that are not for the platform
       * we are building for
       */
      const packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(buildPath, "package.json")).toString());

      packageJson.dependencies = {
        serialport: "^12.0.0",
      };

      fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve(buildPath, "package.json"), JSON.stringify(packageJson));
      spawnSync("npm", ["install", "--omit=dev"], {
        cwd: buildPath,
        stdio: "inherit",
        shell: true,
      });

      const prebuilds = globSync(`${buildPath}/**/prebuilds/*`);
      const matchString = new RegExp(`prebuilds/${platform}`);
      prebuilds.forEach(function (path) {
        if (!path.match(matchString)) {
          fs.rmSync(path, { recursive: true });
        }
      });
    },
  }
};

export default config;


The above code was referred to the repository in the link below.
https://github.com/Dygmalab/Bazecor

Don't add it to externals. externals mean do not bundle that package, while you should bundle that package into the output.

I've tried erasing the item from externals, but the same problem still occurs. @RickyMo
